# How to convert list of lists to tuple of tuples?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to convert list of lists like:

```
 [['retirement'], ['taxes']]
```

to tuple of tuples like this:

```
(('retirement','retirement'),('taxes','taxes'))
```

Comment: Contrary to popular belief, Stack Overflow is not a debugging service. You do need to do some work up front yourself. For example, you need to tell us what your code is supposed to do, what you expect to happen and where you think the problem may lie. Also see [Are there legitimate "fix my code" questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253787) and the linked [How to Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog post.

Comment: Why're you repeating `'retirement'` and `'taxes'` twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = [['retirement'], ['taxes']]
tuple(((x[0], x[0]) for x in a))
```

If you going to iterate over this, omit tuple.